# Storing image from url into our project in android

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project involving custom google map markers.The custom markers have images on the server, and i am calling a web url using Android Query.This markers are loaded from the web each time the application is loaded.I wanted to store the images onto the drawable folder, but that is not possible.Is there a way to save the images once so that i dont have to load the images each time the app runs?

Comment: you need to cache the file

Comment: please post the android query code. How you loading the image

Answer (score 0):

Why not download the markers from you browser and store it in your drawable or asset folder? That way you don't need to load it from the internet. I'm sure those markers are just small i size maybe could take up 50-100kb ea, or even lesser.

Comment: But other poss tell me that drawable folder is a READ only folder.Can you give me a link as how to store images onto drawable?

Answer (score 0):

you can store ur bitmap image in resource folder and then call MarkerOption class..

```
MarkerOption options=new MarkerOption();
options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Yourimage));
```

refer to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#customize_the_marker_image